# Need timezone based on the ISO country code and city in Java

Tags: timezone

My requirement

:::  To find the timezone based on the city and country code both.   Please share Is there any way to find it? I don't want to go with city only since one city can exist in two or more countries.

And even on city bases - I can find time zone but not for all cities if i am entering Leeds (UK city) , its giving nothing.

```
Set<String> availableTimeZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();


    String cityName = Normalizer.normalize(city, Normalizer.Form.NFKD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}-_ ]", "")
            .replace(' ', '_');

    List<String> possibleTimeZones = availableTimeZones.stream().filter(zid -> zid.endsWith("/" + cityName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `one city can exist in two or more countries` ... this is not very common, and even if it did happen, most likely the two halves of the city would still have the same timezone.

Comment: There are many, many ways to do this. Find an available web service. Create your own database. You aren't saying enough about your requirements, what API's you may or may not already be trying to use, etc.

Comment: @Tim, I think he means that one city *name*, like, say "Manchester", can be in more than one country, not talking about a single physical city split between two countries!

Comment: You'll need to think about more than just English if you want all cities of the world

Comment: Do you have any other information?  Lat/long?  Airport code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Rough way I found to achieve is -

private static String getSourceLocalTimeZone(String countryCode, String city, String sourceLocalTimeZone) {
        String[] timeZones = com.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(countryCode);

        for (String timeZone : timeZones) {
            String cityFromTimeZone = null;
            String[] value = timeZone.split("/");
            if (value != null && value.length > 0) {
                cityFromTimeZone = value[value.length - 1].replace("_", " ");
            }
            if (city!=null && city.matches("(.*)" + cityFromTimeZone + "(.*)")) {
                sourceLocalTimeZone = timeZone;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (sourceLocalTimeZone == null || (sourceLocalTimeZone.isEmpty())) {
            if(timeZones.length>0)
            sourceLocalTimeZone = timeZones[0];
        }
        return sourceLocalTimeZone;
    }

Dependency -
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
        </dependency>
```